# Extbase: Check if a form has been submitted in a controller action

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have got a form in which I want to show html links. To avoid that a user looses form inputs in case clicking the link, I want to inform the user before he leaves the form.

To achieve that, I tried

```
public function registerAction(Registration $registration = null) {
    $formHasBeenSubmitted = !is_null($registration);
    $this->view->assign('formHasBeenSubmitted', $formHasBeenSubmitted);
}
```

But it is always false.

What is the correct way to find out if the form for a specific action has been submitted?

Update after [undkos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43515178/7173655):

- I would like to show the message in case the form has been submitted but validation errors have been showing up and of course also as soon as the user started entering data.
- Behind a link there is a form which edits data (postal addresses) which are shown on the main form and should be updated there after editing.

Comment: That means you have a `createAction` that loops a user back to `registerAction` if validation fails? Does your form work in general in that case (i.e. show the values that had been filled in and validation error messages?

Comment: Looping back to `registerAction` in case of validation errors is extbase default behaviour and makes perfectly sense because the user has to adjust data in the form.
Yes, the form is working as excepted in that case.

Comment: That‘s strange then. Have you debugged the value of `$registration` when validation fails?

Comment: `$registration` is false in both cases: loading the form the first time and on validation errors

Answer (score 0):

As a user I don‘t care if the form has been submitted or "just" filled in - hence I suggest to create a modal whenever there‘s data in your form.
Another possibility of improving usability is to create links with `target` attribute. Both, modal and target, impose their own issues so it‘s always a trade-off.

Comment: Thanks for your message, which is actually a different approach but not an answer to my question.

Comment: I see. A comment would have been adequate :-)